# Inner Join between table and a subquery on the same table

Tags: sql-server, subquery, inner-join

SQL server 2012.

Edit:
my original query was more complex than it should be, since I tried to do a Distinct query on a subset of the fields in the table and join that on the table itself to get the other (text) fields. the following query does the trick as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p1.id
    ,p1.Name
    ,CAST( p1.[Description] AS nvarchar(max)) AS Description
    ,( SELECT [Category] + ', '
           FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p2
          WHERE p2.Id = p1.Id
          ORDER BY Name
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Categories
  FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p1
  ORDER BY p1.Id
```

I have a table with data similar to this (multiple records per company that are identical except for the category field):

```
+----+------+-----------------+----------+
| Id | Name | Description     | Category |
+----+------+-----------------+----------+
| 1  | AAA  | <loads of text> | cat1     |
| 1  | AAA  | <loads of text> | cat2     |
| 2  | BBB  | <even more text>| cat1     |
| 2  | BBB  | <even more text>| cat3     |
+----+------+-----------------+----------+
```

I'm trying to make a query to get this result (unique records per company and categories aggregated into 1 field):

```
| 1  | AAA  | <loads of text> | cat1, cat2 |
| 2  | BBB  | <even more text>| cat1, cat3 |
```

Using information from various topics on SO I've come up with this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Id
    ,t2.Name
    ,t2.[Description]
    ,t1.Category
FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS t2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p1.Id
      ,( SELECT [Category] + ', '
           FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p2
          WHERE p2.Id = p1.Id
          ORDER BY Name
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Category
  FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p1
  ) AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
  ORDER BY t1.Id
```

The query result has a record for every record in the Company table, with the categories aggregated into the category field:

```
+----+------+-----------------+------------+
| Id | Name | Description     | Category   |
+----+------+-----------------+------------+
| 1  | AAA  | <loads of text> | cat1, cat2 |
| 1  | AAA  | <loads of text> | cat1, cat2 |
| 2  | BBB  | <even more text>| cat1, cat3 |
| 2  | BBB  | <even more text>| cat1, cat3 |
+----+------+-----------------+------------+
```

I thought INNER JOIN would only select rows if both tables have a match.
The subquery produces by itself the expected result (one record per Id with the categories aggregated). I tried another group by clause over the entire query, but that fails because I can't include the Description field in the group clause since it's a text type field.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use distinct if description is the  same AND discard description OR aggregate description also

Comment: I need the description in the query result, and I can't aggregate it, I would get 10 times the same text in the description field.

Comment: Just add GROUP BY Id, Name, Description.

Comment: Group by fails because Description is a text field, and they can't be included in Group by clauses. And I can't include a field in the SELECT clause when it's not in the Group by clause.

Comment: @tanner: I can't use a server function unfortunately (company policy)

Comment: Ugh. The text datatype has been deprecated because it is a pain to work with. Just cast the Description column as varchar(max) in your select and your group by. I would recommend seeing if you can change the datatype to varchar(max) instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a DISTINCT in the outer query.  This should solve your problem unless the Descriptions/Names are different for some of the rows which may be entirely possible since your database table should probably have been two tables and likely you never wrote any code to make sure description/name stayed the same for every ID.  If you have a compound unique index on id, name and description, then you are likely ok.

If you do have the problem of multiple descriptions you will need to use an aggregate to fix the problem in the outer query. Or you will need to fix the data and add the unique index to prevent a future occurance.

As far as why you are having this problem, the join is working just fine but what you have is a one-many relationship between the derived table and the other table. That is why you are getting multiple records and why distinct should fix it unless the data for an id is different for name and description.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.Id
    ,t2.Name
    ,cast(t2.[Description] as nvarchar(max))
    ,t1.Category
FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS t2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p1.Id
      ,( SELECT [Category] + ', '
           FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p2
          WHERE p2.Id = p1.Id
          ORDER BY Name
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Category
  FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p1
  ) AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
  ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Alternatively you can fix your bad table design.

Comment: Tried that already:
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Oops didn't notice that it was text. Should it acutally be text? You shoudl not  be using a text dataype in SQL Server 2012. You shoudl be using varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). If possible I would convert to those or you can cast to one of those in the query and see if that works.

Comment: The description fields are identical for all records with the same Id. In fact the table is the result of a more complex query combining several tables. I was planning on integrating that query into the above one once I have this working the way it should.

Comment: The tables and fields were made quite some time ago (not by me) and I do not have the option of changing any of them. I could try converting the text fields in the query that produces the Company table, but I'm afraid some might get truncated (we're talking 1000's of records here)

Comment: VARchar(max) and nvarchar(max) will not truncate the data. They can store as much information as a text field. You really should refactor the database to use them but I realize this is not always possible. However text is a deprecated data type and replacing fields using it should be a priority.

Comment: That worked! Casting the description field to nvarchar(max) in the query allowed selecting it as DISTINCT.

Comment: @mark, that is one of themany reasons why text is deprecated and you should be using the varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) data types instead. It si much easier to query and to update the newer datatypes.

Comment: I'll pass on the comments about the text data type to the people responsible for the database design. However this is an old DB which will eventually be phased out from our operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    t1.Id ,
                    t2.Name ,
                    t2.[Description] ,
                    t1.Category ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.Id, t2.Name,
                                        t1.Category ORDER BY t1.id ) row_num
          FROM      [dbo].[Company] AS t2
                    INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                        p1.Id ,
                                        ( SELECT    [Category] + ', '
                                          FROM      [dbo].[Company] AS p2
                                          WHERE     p2.Id = p1.Id
                                          ORDER BY  Name
                                        FOR
                                          XML PATH('')
                                        ) AS Category
                                 FROM   [dbo].[Company] AS p1
                               ) AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
        ) t1
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Comment: Tried that already: Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: update the query. It is a bit ugly, but supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

To get around the nasty issue of using text as a datatype you can cast that column when you pull it. If at all possible, I would change the column permanently to varchar(max).

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Id
    , t2.Name
    , cast(t2.[Description] as varchar(max)) as Description
    , t1.Category
FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS t2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p1.Id
      ,( SELECT [Category] + ', '
           FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p2
          WHERE p2.Id = p1.Id
          ORDER BY Name
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Category
  FROM [dbo].[Company] AS p1
  ) AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
  GROUP BY Id
    , Name
    , cast(t2.[Description] as varchar(max))
  ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate of what HLGEM suggested earlier.